# 2D Drawing for Jupyter?

Tags: python, graphics, 2d, jupyter

I teach intro computer science classes, and I like to do so using 2D graphics.  I've been using John Zelle's excellent [graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf) library, but I want to migrate to using Jupyter with my students so I need a new graphics solution. This needs to be accessible to students as early as 8th grade with no programming experience.

All I'm looking for is basic rectangle/ellipse/arc/polygon/line functionality, with the ability to control stroke and fill colors.  Plus image import.  But I want the API to be as simple as possible.

1. [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) is the obvious choice, but the syntax is kind of messy and it *wants* to be used for graphing, so it takes some extra steps to clean things up into a basic drawing screen.
2. [toyplot](https://toyplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a simplified and prettier matplotlib, but as far as I can tell it doesn't include basic shapes, it's *only* for charting/plotting
3. The [vincent](https://vincent.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) API is about as clean as I could ask for (although I'll ask for more anyway...see below) but it doesn't support arbitrary shapes, just charting/plotting
4. svg can do everything I want but the syntax is overly complicated for beginners
5. ditto for [d3 via javascript magics](http://blog.thedataincubator.com/2015/08/embedding-d3-in-an-ipython-notebook/)

Although I'd be content if vincent had basic shapes, after working with graphics.py for a while I think I'd prefer something that doesn't use objects.  The Processing3 api is probably the ideal, in that (for example) you call a rectangle() function, which uses the current stroke and fill settings, rather than create a Rectangle object, set its properties, and then tell it to draw itself.  (Yes, I personally prefer the latter, but I find that it just adds a layer of confusion for beginners.)

So...what options am I missing?

Comment: why don't you use your loved gaphics.py with jupyter? sure the results are in an extra window, but jupyter let's you add screenshots, markdown exercise text etc. Just use both. :)

Answer (score 0):

for young students maybe turtle graphics is most appropriate

to get a feel this is a sample code from docs.python.org:

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```